# APIC error on CPU1: 60(60) in dmesg what does it mean?

Tags: linux, centos, central-processing-unit, dmesg

APIC error on CPU1: 60(60) in my dmesg log. What does it mean? Should I be worried! Is this some hardware issue?

Comment: Please be more detailed: OS and kernel version, and type of hardware.

Also, are you on bare metal or in a virtual machine?

Comment: bare matal centos 5.6, 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 x86_64 type of hardware its simple workstation(desktop) working as server, CPU Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2220  @ 2.40GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates a failure in the Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller. The failure means that the kernel was not able to communicate with the CPU APIC (wrong message).
There isn't a unique solution to this; the cause may be:

- a buggy driver (network card driver is a good candidate, as for unused modules that kernel loads anyway);
- an old or defective BIOS;
- some kind of wrong setting in the BIOS;
- a broken motherboard or (uncommon) CPU.

If you experience a lot of crashes, freezings, strange behaviour of software, you can try:

- boot with the "noapic" kernel parameter;
- upgrade BIOS;
- upgrade CentOS to 5.7 or 6.0;

Otherwise, if everything works, dont'worry....